# Get a file from a directory dynamically in Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, camel-ftp

I need my program to fetch a file from a directory, but this file will be fetched dynamically, every time I start the scheduler it will have to fetch the latest product.
All of this in Apache Camel, but I have no idea how to do it.

from("file:c:/camelin?fileName=test.csv&noop=true")

for the moment I take it in static mode, but I need it in dynamic.
Anyone can help me?

I need to do all of this without SFTP.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.